# Check my proof of 0 < |r - q| < epsilon. (Real # - Rational #)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality, proof-writing, rational-numbers

I am working on this exercise:

$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \ \exists q \in Q  \text{ where } 0 < |r - q| < \varepsilon $$

To clarify, r is a real number, q is a rational number. This is what I have so far:

$$ 0 < |r - q| < \varepsilon $$
$$ -\varepsilon < (r-q) < \varepsilon $$
$$ r - \varepsilon < q < r + \varepsilon $$

Then making use of a given theorem that "Between any two distinct real numbers there is a rational number and an irrational number," I conclude the proof by claiming that the inequality must hold by the theorem and given that $r - \epsilon$ and $r + \epsilon$ are two distinct real numbers.

Is this sufficient for the proof? Otherwise, would appreciate some help on how to proof the above inequality more rigorously.

I recall the Archimedean Property that for each positive real number r, there exists a positive integer n such that $\frac{1}{n} < r$. There is a hint to use this condition, but I am unsure how to apply it into the proof.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your proof is backwards. You're starting from the thing that you want to prove, then working backwards from that. Go the other way: start from what you know, and show that such a $q$ has to exist.

Comment: You already asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3070774/real-analysis-inequality-proof-involving-reals-and-rationals-0-r-q-var) yesterday

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the density of the rationals, then your proof is upside down, i.e., to fix it, go from $r - \epsilon < q < r + \epsilon$ to your claim.

Nevertheless, you're using a rocket launcher against a fly; in fact, the two statements are pretty much equal, so it's almost circular reasoning. Suppose WLOG $r > 0$; since you have the Archimedian property, fix $\epsilon$ and pick the least $n$ such that $\epsilon \geq 1/n$. If $r < \epsilon$ pick $q=0$ and you're done. Otherwise, pick the biggest $m$ such that $r - m/n \geq 0$; since $r - (m+1)/n < 0$ (because $m$ is maximal), $r-m/n < 1/n \leq \epsilon$. Pick $q = m/n$ and we're done.